# Android database cloud

Tags: android, database, cloud

I have a football Quiz (on android). Every week I want to update the DB in a DB stored on the network. Change every week randomly questions and not be so monotonous.

I need some method to **update the DB** from a **cloud** or something. I have a couple of days looking online, I thought about using some google service but all the guides I look lead me to something that is deprecated or mess up and begins to send me to many different places and I get lost.

**I would like to find out a service that allows me to have a database on the network from which I can make calls from my app easily to obtain the data.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer: https://www.parse.com/ in case you need any backend system.

Comment: welcome. Please mark the comment as resolved so that other can refer to it.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry i have not understood the question properly, from whatever i understood your are either asking

1. Is it possible to update the local app db from cloud?
   I am not sure of any direct method to do this. I think you can enable push notification in your app and make the app update your local db in response to the push notification.
2. A freely available cloud db which you can use in your app.
   Not sure whether there are cloud db freely available, not sure of this either.  you maybe able to integrate with dropbox/google through api and use it as a datasource if your are not able to find a db.

Comment: I only need one onlyne store for my data base and one method for interact with it from my app

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8695771/free-cloud-database-service-for-home-development) Check for freely available db